# running a script exec command from php

Tags: php, exec

I have an application where I need to run a PHP script by exec() function of php.

> "php
>   /var/www/server/data/scripts/ThreadHandler.php
>   145596 >
>   /var/www/server/data/logs/threads/thread.145596.log
>   2>&1 &"

also tried

> "php
>   /var/www/server/data/scripts/ThreadHandler.php
>   145596 >
>   /var/www/server/data/logs/threads/thread.145596.log
>   2>&1 "

I am running above command with `exec()` function of PHP, but it is not getting run, I can't track any error. please suggest any change.

Comment: @codaddict, he is `can't track any error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
passthru('php -f /var/www/server/data/scripts/ThreadHandler.php 145596 > 
         /var/www/server/data/logs/threads/thread.145596.log 2>&1');
```

Also, try to run it from linux command line

Comment: I have tried from linux command , It was error of "threads" folder's writing permission. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try defining $output and $return_var arguments for exec and print their values :

```
$output = array();
$rv = null;
exec("your command", $output, $rv);
print_r($rv);
print_r($output);
```